# Switching between sets of buffers

Tags: buffers, window, frames

I often work with Tmux and I really like the ability to have multiple windows where each window has a custom set of panes. This allows me to quickly switch between layouts without losing anything.

So far in Emacs I know how to navigate buffers, switch from one buffer to another, close a buffer, open a new buffer, split the window and access a list of buffers. What I haven't been able to do is to have multiple custom setups and be able to quickly switch between them. Like so:

[image]

How would one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done very easily if you are using [`ivy`](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper). All you got to do is execute the command `ivy-push-view` when are on a window setup you like and give it a specific name (by default the name of the ivy-view goes like `{} buffer1 buffer2`).

Once you've pushed a window config you like to `ivy-views`, you can then change from any window configuration to the one you saved before using `switch-to-buffer` and selecting the view you pushed before and the whole window configuration will be restored :)

It's incredibly simple and so damn useful. Also, if you're using `desktop-save-mode` you can also chose to save `ivy-views` in it so that everytime you restore the desktop save file, you restore `ivy-views` as well.